# Duplicate _id in new_results

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I have a meteor collection and I want to allow user to edit several items at once and click kind of Save button to update them all.

This is my collection:

```
EmpresasUsuarias = new Mongo.Collection("empresasUsuarias");
```

And I do this on client to have it in $scope:

```
$scope.empresasUsuarias = $meteor.collection(EmpresasUsuarias, false);
```

Thing is: when user adds some items and clicks Save, I collect (only) the new items in an array and send to server via meteor method. In server, the method inserts items in the (mongo) collection. Everything is fine until flow returns to client. There, the collection receives 'back' all those new records ***again*** and they duplicate, and the error appears in the (client) console:

```
Duplicate _id in new_results
```

Whant I think is happening is the subscription/publishing mechanism activates when the items are inserted and send them back to client; but they already exists there and Meteor thinks they are duplicated (ie: Meteor does not syncs items but duplicates them and finish with error message).

I must say that I am assigning _id for each new record in the client, so when they reach the server they *already* have an _id.

What am I doing wrong here? Why does Meteor think those items are different and says they are duplicates?

Many thanks in advance for helping and bye ...

Comment: I think it is better not to assign _id, but to leave them auto-generated to prevent such errors

Comment: I don't assign _id to collection in client now ... same results. I'm doing something simple: 1) subscribe to a very small collection; 2) $scope.MyCollection = $meteor.collection(MyCollection , false); 3) $scope.MyCollection.push({ name: 'my name'}) (several times); 4) Save using meteor method (in server): MyCollection.insert(item) (several times, because I have many items to insert). 5) List ($scope) shows duplicate items (client). 6) Error: Duplicate _id in new results. 7) What am I doing wrong? Many thanks ...

Comment: can you publish it in github so we can reproduce?

Comment: Hi @oshai, it apparently works; please see bellow; thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is what I did to solve my problem. I just stopped my collection before saving and restated it after saving.

1. Save user edits in `$scope` in an array
2. Stopped collection: `$scope.MyCollection.stop()`
3. `$scope.MyCollection.length = 0;`
4. Call server (Meteor) method to save edits (passing array with edits)
5. Subscribe to meteor collection (again)
6. `$scope.MyCollection = $meteor.collection(MyCollection, false)`

I keep getting my `_id`s (for new documents) in client. I don't know if I'm doing it correctly, just know that, apparently, works.